# Cannot Add authentication to your bot via Azure Bot Service

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I want to try the demo on Add authentication to your bot via Azure Bot Service which based on the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0, what i am using is Demonstrates OAuthCard support in the v3 C# SDK, using AAD v2, but i always failed when i use bot emulator to connect the bot service.
i think i set the correct the settings in the webconfig.

Comment: `i always failed when i use bot emulator to connect the bot service` Do you mean that you can not connect to your bot even though you provide correct AppId and AppPassword?

Comment: Hi Zero! 

There is currently an ongoing issue with connecting the AAD v2 authentication with both the v3 and v4 of the emulator. You can track the progress on: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/678 As soon as it is resolved, I'll post the work around answer here. Additonally, the tutorial will be updated with the new steps to take.